# Invoking a function that is inside an IIFE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am successfully being able to call a function (`function1`) which exists outside of an IIFE.

My question is how can I invoke `function2` ? Right now it returns `function2` is undefined. I am thus sure that this is not the right way to call a function from an IIFE. So I would love to know the correct way and appreciate a brief explanation.

```js
function function1() {
    alert('1');
}

(function($){ 
  function function2(){
      alert('2');
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" onkeypress="function1();"/>
<input type="text" onkeypress="function2();"/>
```

Comment: `function2` is accessible inside of the IIFE only.

Comment: @Teemu . So there is no way I can access it outside of the IIFE?

Comment: You need to make it public

Comment: No way, no workaround, as long as `function2` is declared within the IIFE.

Comment: Oh. Thanks... @Teemu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `onkeypress` attribute runs in the global context, so it can't see the function inside your IIFE.

Using attributes for event listeners like this is not a recommended practice.

Instead of doing it that way, it's better to attach the event listener from code inside your IIFE, perhaps like this:

```js
(function($){

  function function2(){
      alert('2');
  }

  $('#test2').on( 'keypress', function2 );

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test2" />
```

I added an `id` attribute to the input element, but you could also use a `class` or other ways to identify it when you add the event listener.

Comment: Didn't see yours before I posted. I'll delete mine if you think it's too similar.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Oh, don't delete yours. It shows another way to select the element, which could be useful to the OP. In fact, it looks like Chirag got there before both of us. Great minds think alike! :-)

Comment: Haha! Considered deleting mine too. But had put in too much love and typing to throw it away :D

Answer (score 3):

Your function is out of scope in the code that you have provided. You could either move function two out of the IIFE or register your event on the inputs inside the IIFE.

```js
function one() {
  alert(1)
}


(function($) {
  function two() {
    alert(2)
  }
  $('.one').keypress(one)
  $('.two').keypress(two)
})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="one" type="text" />
<input class="two" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery, of course!

```js
function function1() {
  console.log('1');
}

(function($){ 
  $('input').eq(1).keypress(function function2() {
    console.log('2');
  })
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" onkeypress="function1();"/>
<input type="text"/>
```

Yes I'm aware I completely side-stepped the issue.

The point is, you should be doing what is considered good practice, and not trying to force something which is considered bad practice into working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it if you make `function2` public

```js
function function1() {
    alert('1');
}

var myFuncs = (function($){ 
  function function2(){
      alert('2');
  }
  return {
      fun2:function2

}
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" onkeypress="function1();"/>
<input type="text" onkeypress="myFuncs.fun2();"/>
```